# Cuda error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__device__'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, cuda

The file is named with .cu extension. It is complaining about my device function definitions...  What other information do you need?

```
d.cu(96): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__device__'
d.cu(96): error C2085: 'distance' : not in formal parameter list
d.cu(96): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

Actual function at line 96: (Float2d is a struct)

```
__device__ 
float distance(Float2d A, Float2d B){
return sqrtf( (A.x-B.x)*(A.x-B.x) + (A.y-B.y)*(A.y-B.y) );
}
```

Comment: Yes, the file is set to be compiled by cuda/c++ in the file properties (listed under source files)

Comment: you think it sounds like nvcc is not being involved?

Comment: That was my guess indeed. But good to read you've solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem: For some reason (a while back) I had included the `.cu` file in the `.c` file. Don't know why/how maybe I was drunk. So this was an ID:107 error.